# extract html to a helper method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a helper in my app with this code:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def cms(key)
    if Text.find_by_key(key)
      Text.find_by_key(key).content
    else
      nil
    end
  end

  def cms2(key)
    if Text.find_by_key(key)
      Text.find_by_key(key)
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

and in my view files i have this:

```
<%if cms('front2')==nil%>
    <%if admin_signed_in?%>
        <%=link_to "create", new_text_path(:key => 'front2')%>
    <%end%>
<%else%>
    <%=raw(cms('front2'))%>
    <%if admin_signed_in?%>
        <%=link_to("Edit", edit_text_path(cms2('front2')), :class=>"editcms")%>
    <%end%>     
<%end%>
```

I want to extract the html portion of this code so i can call a helper like this:

```
<%= new_method('front2') %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _extract the html portion_? Do you mean you want to place the `link_to` helpers within your view helper?

Comment: yeah that instead of adding the second portion of the code there in the views, i can add the last line of code and i get that returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper 
module ApplicationHelper
  def cms(key, admin_signed_in)
    if key.nil?
        if admin_signed_in
            if Text.find_by_key(key)
              link_to 'create', new_text_path(:key => key)
            else
              nil
            end
        end
    else
        text = Text.find_by_key(key).content
        if admin_signed_in
            "#{text} #{link_to('Edit', edit_text_path(cms2(key)), :class => 'editcms')}".html_safe
        else
            text
        end
    end
  end
end

# in your view
<%= cms('front_2') %>
```

Comment: hey, good answer but i need to show the text and the edit link when the admin is signed in, both of them, not just one

Comment: Have you actually implemented this? That's precisely what `"#{text} #{link_to('Edit', edit_text_path(cms2(key)), :class => 'editcms')}"` does.

Comment: oh ok i see it now, i will implement it right away and message you back

Comment: im sorry, but its returning the link as a string like this:

this is a test <a href="/texts/14/edit" class="editcms">Edit</a>

Comment: What _should_ the string be returning? Do you mean that the HTML is being rendered as a string?

Comment: i want it to return it as a link not the string

Comment: Try `<%= cms('front_2').html_safe %>`. I've update my answer in turn.

Comment: yes this works, but is there any way to return is safe from the helper?

Comment: I really can't imagine that it matter all that much _where_ `html_safe` is invoked, since you'll need to invoke it _somewhere_. I suppose you can try appending it to the end of your return values in your helper. I've adjusted my code to match.

Comment: and in your expertise, is it better this aproach, or with a partial?

Comment: Either works. Partials have benefits, but both helpers and partials should really be applied depending on use case. I provided code for a helper because that's what your question __very__ specifically asked about. I hope what was provided is sufficient to warrant accepting/upvoting the answer.